# How remove the text between curly bracket

Tags: string, python-3.x

I have strings extracted from a csv file. I want to know how to remove the text between the curly brackets from the string using Python, ex:

```
string = 'some text hear { bracket } some text here'
```

I want to get:

```
some text hear some text here
```

I hope anyone can help me to solve this problem, thank you.

EDIT:
answer

```
import re
string = 'some text hear { bracket } some text here'
string = re.sub(r"\s*{.*}\s*", " ", string)
print(string)
```

Comment: You can also do it like so: `print(s.split(' {')[0],s.split('} ')[1])`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could use a regular expression for this:

```
import re
string = 'some text hear { bracket } some text here'
string = re.sub(r"\s*{.*}\s*", " ", string)
print(string)
```

Output:

```
some text hear some text here
```

Answer (score 4):

Given:

```
>>> s='some text here { bracket } some text there'
```

You can use `str.partition` and `str.split`:

```
>>> parts=s.partition(' {')
>>> parts[0]+parts[2].rsplit('}',1)[1]
'some text here some text there'
```

Or just partition:

```
>>> p1,p2=s.partition(' {'),s.rpartition('}')
>>> p1[0]+p2[2]
'some text hear some text there'
```

If you want a regex:

```
>>> re.sub(r' {[^}]*}','',s)
'some text hear some text there'
```

Answer (score -1):

Like this:

```
import re
re.sub(r"{.*}", "{{}}", string)
```

Comment: If you know what you need to replace, this will unnecessarily load the `re` module and is far slower than the `replace` method on a string.

Comment: This will leave behind the curly braces themselves, which is not what OP requested

Answer (score -2):

```
>>> s = 'some text here { word } some other text'
>>> s.replace('{ word }', '')
    'some text here  some other text'
```

Comment: This will only replace exact matches of `{ word }`, but not any substring enclosed in curly brackets.

Comment: Well spotted! Who knew?